# Jcl include condition

Tags: sorting, jcl

I have written an include condition as below:

```
OUTFIL FILES=01,INCLUDE=(35,3,CH,EQ,'A01',AND, 
(1,3,CH,EQ,C'AAA',OR,1,3,CH,EQ,C'BBB',OR,1,3,CH,EQ,C'CCC'))
```

It is working. I need to whether the below condition will also work in the similar way.

```
OUTFIL FILES=01,INCLUDE=(35,3,CH,EQ,'A01',AND,(1,3,CH,EQ,C'AAA,BBB,CCC'))
```

Is this also correct?

```
OUTFIL FILES=01,INCLUDE=(35,3,CH,EQ,'A01',AND, 
(1,3,CH,EQ,C'AAA',OR,1,3,CH,EQ,C'BBB',OR,1,3,CH,EQ,C'CCC'))


OUTFIL FILES=01,INCLUDE=(35,3,CH,EQ,'A01',AND,(1,3,CH,EQ,C'AAA,BBB,CCC'))
```

Both jobs are running fine. I am fetching the data from a tape file.

So not sure both the conditions are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Both forms are correct. The first one (longer) is more explicit.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=statement-substring-comparison-tests